# Probability of $X \in A$ using Lebesgue measure - proof verification

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, solution-verification

This is a really basic problem for advanced probability, but there are some bits I can't get my head around. If $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ is a probability triple (Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$) with $\mathcal{F}$ Borel $\sigma-$algebra and rv $X(\omega)$ defined as
$$
X(\omega) = \Bigg\{
\begin{align}
\omega \ \text{if } 0 \leq \omega < \frac{1}{2}\\
\omega^2 \ \ \ \text{if } \frac{1}{2} \leq \omega\leq 1
\end{align}
$$
If $A \in \mathcal{F}$, s.t. $A=[\frac{1}{4}, \frac{3}{4}]$, I want to find $P(X \in A)$. From the definition of $A, \ P(X \in A) = P(\{\omega: X(\omega) \leq x\})$.

Splitting the set into two intervals, finding the preimages $X^{-1}$, and using Lebesgue measure on $\Omega$,
\begin{align}
P(X \in A) &= P(\frac{1}{4}\leq X(\omega) \leq \frac{1}{2}) + P( \frac{1}{2}\leq X(\omega) \leq \frac{3}{4}) \\  
&= \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} - \frac{1}{2} +\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\
&= \frac{2\sqrt{3}-1}{4}
\end{align}
I'm quite confident this is correct, but when I consider $A=[0,1]$, I think it must be that $P(X \in A)=1$ because $A$ partitions $\Omega$, and when I use the same calculation as above, I get
$$
P(X \in A) = \frac{1}{2}-0 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} - \frac{1}{2} + 1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} = 1
$$
Nevertheless, I'd like to know if there are any issues with my logic here.

Comment: $A=(A\cap[0,1/2])\cup(A\cap(1/2,1])$. In your decomposition of $A$, $\frac12$ is "counted" twice.

Comment: @OliverDiaz It's what I don't get about Lebesgue measure. I understand $A_i$ partition $\Omega$, but I don't quite understand why $X^{-1}(B_1 \cup B_2) = X^{-1}(B_1) \cup X^{-1}(B_2)\setminus X^{-1}(B_1 \cap B_2)$

Comment: This are general properties of the preimage operation:
$$X^{-1}(A\cup B)=X^{-1}(A) \cup X^{-1}(B)$$ $$X^{-1}(A\setminus B)=X^{-1}(A)\setminus X^{-1}(B)$$ $$X^{-1}(A\cap B)=X^{-1}(A)\cap X^{-1}(B)$$

For any measure $\mu$, $\mu(U\cup V)=\mu(U)+\mu(V)-\mu(U\cap V)$. This follows from 
$$\mu(U\cup B)=\mu(U\cup (V\setminus U\cap V)=\mu(U)+\mu(V\setminus(U\cap V))$$
since $U$ and $V\setminus(V\cap U)$ are disjoint, and 
$$\mu(V)=\mu\big((V\setminus U)\cup (U\cap V)\big)=\mu(V\setminus U)+\mu(U\cap V) $$

since $V\setminus U$ and $U\cap V$ are disjoint

Comment: @OliverDiaz sorry to bother you again, but $X^{-1}([\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{2}] = [\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{2}]$ for $\omega < \frac{1}{2}$ but also $X^{-1}([\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{2}] = [\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}]$ for $\omega >\frac{1}{2}$, so $X^{-1}$. I understand splitting the image of $X$ into two disjoint subsets, but why can't I take $X^{-1}([\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{2}]) = [\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}]$?

Comment: Just make an edit in my answer. I made a silly mistake earlier. Now it should be OK. I meant to have the intervals $[0,1/2)$ and $[1/2,1]$ outside the preimages but did not go well when I  LaTeXed things out.

Comment: OK so my original calculation was correct then. I'm not overcounting in any way by taking preimage $[\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}]$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:
$$
\begin{align}
X^{-1}([1/4,3/4])&=\Big(X^{-1}([1/4,3/4])]\cap[0,1/2)\Big)\cup\Big(X^{-1}[1/4,3/4])\cap[1/2,1]\Big)\\
&=[1/4,1/2)\cup[1/2,\sqrt{3}/2]
\end{align}
$$

Hence

\begin{aligned}
\lambda\big([X^{-1}([1/4,3/4])\big) =\lambda([1/4,1/2)) +\lambda([1/2,\sqrt{3}/2])=\frac14 +\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2}
\end{aligned}

Comment: So one needs to partition $A$ into two disjoint subsets based on domain of $\omega$?

Comment: To use the additivity of the measure yes. Although in this case $\lambda(X^{-1}(\{1/2\}))=\lambda(\{1/\sqrt{2}\})=0$. That is there is not harm here.

Comment: I probably miss something here, but $ X \in A, A=[\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4}]$ is not the same as $X^{-1}(B) = X^{-1}([\frac{1}{4}, \frac{3}{4}])$. Roughly speaking, in the first line of proof you take the intersects of intervals on X-axis ($\omega, [0,\frac{1}{2})$ ) with intervals on Y-axis ($X(\omega), [\frac{1}{4}, \frac{3}{4}])$

Comment: Yes, since $A \subset \Omega$ and intervals are disjoint, then $A=(A \cap I_1) \cup (A \cap I_2) = A_1 \cup A_2$, so, roughly (probably incorrectly) speaking, intervals partition $A$, so each preimage $A_1, A_2$ is determined by the corresponding map $X_1(I_1), X_2(I_2)$

Answer (score 0):

I think your computations are correct. However, you can make one step more explicit, by splitting the universe with the events $(0\leq \omega \leq \frac{1}{2})$ and $(\frac{1}{2}< \omega \leq 1)$. I think this splitting is more crucial than the one with $(0\leq X(\omega) \leq \frac{1}{2})$ and $(\frac{1}{2}< X(\omega) \leq 1)$.